# What are all of the unlockables in the Reckoning demo?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

The *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* demo unlocks some items for use in the retail version. What are all the unlocks? Does finishing any of the quest chains in the village unlock anything?

I've already got the items one gets for signing into the EA servers (including the *Reckoning* armor for *Mass Effect 3*) as well as the Infernal Helm for meeting the Fateweaver and I got the *Reckoning* weapon for *Mass Effect 3* when the demo timer ran out.

Are there any more unlockables and how do I get them?

Comment: This question is about Amalur, not ME3. Please stop adding the Mass Effect 3 tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Destructoid](http://www.destructoid.com/video-of-the-me3-and-reckoning-demo-item-unlocks-219581.phtml):

**Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning demo item unlocks for Mass Effect 3:**

- **Reckoner Knight Armor:** This armor will maximize damage done in close-quarters combat while a beefed–up power cell feeds energy into weapon systems to increase projectile velocity.
- **The Chakram Launcher**: This weapon uses a fabricator to manufacture lightweight, explosive ammunition discs. This weapon is earned after completing the Reckoning demo and watching the trailer at the end.

**Mass Effect 3 demo item unlocks for Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning:**

- **N7 Armor:** Players can unlock special armor inspired by Commander Shepard’s iconic N7 battle armor including Helm, Cuirass, Gauntlets, Chausses and Greaves.
- **Onmiblade Daggers**: A holographic blade stemming from Commander Shepard’s Omni-Tool, the Omni-blade allows players to stab enemies in close combat. Once players install and play the Mass Effect 3 demo, they will unlock the daggers.

**Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning demo item unlocks for Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning:**

- **Twist of Fate Card:** This card boosts the player’s ice resistance and is immediately unlocked when he or she activates the Reckoning demo using his or her Origin account.
- **Twinned Souls Chakram:** A unique weapon that damages enemies while boosting player health and mana in Reckoning.
- **The Infernal Helm:** Unlocked after completing the Reckoning Tutorial Mode, this protective helmet increases players’ fire damage throughout Amalur.